# User and password requested when ext4 mounted with Live USB boot

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb

I have a live USB with Ubuntu 14.04.3 on fat32, and then there's an ext4 partition beside it.

When I put the ext4 partition in it changed everything.

Now, when I boot to the USB it asks for a login name and password.
The only catch is, i never made a login name and password.

It's kind of like Linux is super happy to see its good old ext4 file system and now it's changed behaviour.

Anyone know why this computer mystery is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there is a previous system on the `ext4` partition and your BIOS settings (or as a distant second possibility, the USB boot loader) is configured to mount that as the system root if one is available.

Configure your BIOS to prefer to boot from USB over any fixed disk and you should be fine.

Down the line, maybe reinstall the `ext4` partition to contain useful stuff instead if what is there now isn't useful to you.